# Upstream proxy and CA configuration

Tags: ssl, mitmproxy, upstream

I try to configure mitmproxy to work with an upstream proxy in another domain.

To be more explicit, i have a platform with its own domain (e.g mydomain.com) and to access to interne i need to go through my company proxy with its own domain too (e.g. company.com).

I générate certificate for mitmproxy and i have the CA and the key used to generate the certificate. I rename them as mitmproxy-ca.pem (key + ca) and mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem (certificate) and put them into .mitmproxy folder. It seems to work fine even if i didn't manage to test completely.

But for the upstream proxy ssl configuration, i put the company CA into .mitmproxy folder and name it (mycompany-ca.pem). I configured config.yaml file with : ssl_verify_upstream_trusted_ca: "/home/mitmproxy/.mitmproxy/mycompany-ca.pem".

But when i try to use mitproxy to curl https://www.google.com i've got this error :

```
W.X.Y.Z:57370: client connect
W.X.Y.Z:57370: server connect proxy.mycompany.com (A.B.C.D:8080)
W.X.Y.Z:57370: Server TLS handshake failed. Certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
W.X.Y.Z:57370: GET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/2.0
 << Certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
W.X.Y.Z:57370: server disconnect proxy.mycompany.com (A.B.C.D:8080)
W.X.Y.Z:57370: client disconnect
```

When i use my company proxy for my browser i can see that the certificate subject is google but the issuer is my company proxy information.

More over, the company proxy CA is only a certificate without any key (seems normal) and i use mitmproxy from docker.
And of course when i use --ssl_insecure option it works but i don't want (i'm not allowed) to bypass the upstream proxy certificate verification.

Do you have an idea how to configure upstream SSL certificate control please ?

Comment: This generally sounds about right - which version of mitmproxy are you using, and can you retry with the latest master builds (:dev tag on DockerHub)? What do you see in the event log on master?

Comment: Thanks Maximilian. I already use dev tag.I check how event log works.

Comment: The event log (debug mode : console_eventlog_verbosity: debug and termlog_verbosity: debug) shows what i pasted above : 
info: Proxy server listening at http://*:8080
info: W.X.Y.Z:59374: client connect
info: W.X.Y.Z:59374: server connect proxy.mycompany.com (A.B.C.D:8080)
warn: W.X.Y.Z:59374: Server TLS handshake failed. Certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
info: W.X.Y.Z:59374: server disconnect proxy.mycompany.com (A.B.C.D:8080)
info: W.X.Y.Z:59374: client disconnect

Comment: If you can still reproduce this on dev, please open an issue on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: Issue opened : https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/4419

Comment: Issue closed : The problem was solved by using ssl_verify_upstream_trusted_ca option and concat all CA in one file PEM file.